# tinyMCE editor upload images to user folders and posts

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, tinymce, justboil.me

I'm trying to create a post form for users where they can type something and add pictures in the middle of the text as well.
I'm using tinyMCE + justboilme plugin to be able to use this.
In justboilme I set the folder where all images will go.
Next, from my post form I send contents to an ajax file and upload them to the server. Here's how it looks like:

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="" class="new_post">
   <input type="text" id="post_title" name="post_title" placeholder="Title"><br /><br />
   <textarea id="post_content" cols="40" rows="20"></textarea><br /><br />
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="add_post">
</form>
```

JQUERY

```
$('.new_post').on('submit', function (submit)
{
    var post_title = $('#post_title').val();
    var post_content = $('#post_content').val();

    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "../ajax/ajaxPost.php",
        data: {"title": post_title, "content": post_content},
        success: function (post)
        {
            alert(post);
        }
    });

    submit.preventDefault();
});
```

Ajax

```
session_start();
  require("../Database/DB.php");
  $id = $_SESSION['id'];
  $username = $_SESSION['username'];

  if($_POST) {

    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $content = $_POST['content'];


    $add_post = mysqli_query($DB, "INSERT INTO posts (post_title, post_content, post_user_id, post_date) VALUES ('$title', '$content', '$id', now())");
    if($add_post) {
        echo "OK";
    } else {
        echo "Not ok";
    } 
}
```

Now, all of this works fine and I can see the images. However, every user who posts anything will upload his images to the same folder, which at some point will become clustered. Also I would like to have them organised nicely.
Now all images go to this folder:

```
$config['img_path'] = '/posts';
```

I want to organise images for each user and each post i.e
"/posts/username/postNo/img.jpg"

Any ideas how to deal with this? Or perhaps I should use another html editor or another way? If there is a better way/plugin to do this then please tell me.
Cheers.

Comment: You haven't provided the code that saves the file to disk, so we can't help you.

Additionally be careful about interpolating user provided values directly into a query string, it can make you vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: What do you mean code that saves images to disc? You mean the code saving images to `$config['img_path'] = '/posts';`? This is provided by the plugin.